# How to access an external USB storage device through the Cordova File plugin in Ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, io, usb-drive

I'm creating an application in Ionic in which I want to add the functionality of reading files from external storage devices that are connected to the mobile through micro USB (on Android devices) or Lightning (on iPhones).

After researching about it; I didn't find something that is already built apart from the [File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) which has a great API for read/write access on the mobile itself and the sdcard that is mounted on the device, but I haven't been able to read the USB flash stick that is connected on the mobile.

At the moment I'm testing on an Android device with the below code

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {File} from "@ionic-native/file";
@Injectable()
export class MyClassProvider {

  constructor(public fileNative: File) {}

  public findPathOfMainUSBFolder() {
    let fs = this.fileNative;
    let folders = [fs.applicationDirectory, fs.applicationStorageDirectory, fs.cacheDirectory, fs.dataDirectory, fs.externalRootDirectory, fs.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, fs.externalCacheDirectory, fs.externalDataDirectory, "file:///storage/"];

    for (let mainFolder of folders) {
      this.fileNative.listDir(mainFolder,'').then( success => {
        console.log("success ", mainFolder, "Contents: ", success);
      }, rej => {
        console.log("rej ", mainFolder, "Contents: ", rej);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("err ", mainFolder, "Contents: ", err);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

looping through all the [available directories](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout) to see if it will list the contents of the USB flash stick.
None of these directories points to/is the root directory on the USB though.

Am I missing something, or it is simply not possible to use the File plugin to access the USB flash stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging into the file system and using [File Chooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/) which helped me identify the full path of the files on the USB, I ended up with the below function which creates an array containing one object for each USB device connected that has the path of the USB:

```
public findPathOfMainUSBFolder(callback) {

    let usbDevicesConnected = [];
    this.fileNative.listDir("file:///", "storage").then( success => {
      for (let entry of success) {
        if (entry.isDirectory == true && entry.name != "emulated" && entry.name != "self") {
          usbDevicesConnected.push({path: "file:///storage/", dirName: entry.name});
          console.log("USB ", entry.name, " has been added to the list");
        }
      }
      callback(usbDevicesConnected)
    }, rej => {
      console.log("rej file:///, storage ", "Contents: ", rej);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("err file:///, storage ", "Contents: ", err);
    })

}
```

which can be called as below to list all the files that exist on the root level of the USB:

```
this.findPathOfMainUSBFolder( usbArray => {
  for (let usb of usbArray) {
    this.fileNative.listDir(usb.path, usb.dirName).then( success => {
      console.log("USB with ID " + usb.dirName + " has contents: ", success)
    }, rej => {
      console.log("REJ on USB with ID " + usb.dirName + " : ", rej)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("ERr on USB with ID " + usb.dirName + " : ", err)
    })
  }
})
```

This works on Android mobile phones, but I haven't tested it on iPhone.

Comment: You might also be able to use [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

Comment: @DaveAlden Unfortunately the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) function returns an empty array when the USB flash stick is plugged in. It detects the SD card (if there is one) that is in the mobile though.

Answer (score 0):

```
let usbDevicesConnected = [];
this.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails()
    .then((details) => {
       details.forEach((USBDevice: {
          path: string,
          canWrite: boolean,
          freeSpace: number,
          type: string,
          filePath?: string
       }) => {
        if (USBDevice.canWrite && USBDevice.freeSpace > 100000) {
             usbDevicesConnected.push(USBDevice.filePath);
        }
   });
}).catch();
```

New way I found is implementing android SAF https://github.com/yokodima/USBFilesManager

Comment: Last time I tried this function, it detected only the SD card details. Does this work for you if you connect a USB stick to the USB port of your mobile phone? If yes, which exact version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: @Alexios, This function, it seems to me, does not work if you connect a USB stick to the USB port, it works well if you connect a USB flash drive via an OTG cable.
`"@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.19.1"
"cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1"`